# Angela's Continuity

Tags: marvel, spawn

I became aware of the character [Angela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_(comics)) because she appears in the game Avengers Alliance 2.

Out of curiosity, I did some research into her background, and found it to be somewhat novel. She was originally a character in the Spawn comics published by Image Comics, co-created by Todd McFarlane and Neil Gaiman. She was an angel sent by heaven to fight Spawn, or something along those lines.

Then, when Gaiman joined Marvel Comics, he brought Angela with him. She has now appeared in Marvel comics, starting with the 2013 story [Age of Ultron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Ultron). Apparently, she is now the long lost sister of Thor, raised by angels in a secret tenth realm called "Heven".

However, it looks like that Age of Ultron storyline was set in two alternate universes: Earth-61112 and Earth-26111.

My question is, does Angela exist in any of the main Marvel universes, and are the events of the Spawn comics in any way part of the canon of the universes that she is in?

Comment: She does exist in the main Marvel universe, the time meddling in Age of Ultron (which spawned the alternate universes) was, I believe, what set her or her realm free, but that part wasn't set in one of the alternate universes, but rather the main one.  Original Sin, which filled in her backstory, was also set in the main universe (her Age of Ultron appearance was little more than a cameo, IIRC).  I can't recall if they addressed any of the Spawn backstory, though, whether as hallucinations or anything else so I'll leave someone else to give a more complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Angela (real name: [Aldrif Odinsdottir](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Aldrif_Odinsdottir_(Earth-616))) does exist in the 616 Universe, the main Marvel Comics continuity. A list of appearances can be seen [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Aldrif_Odinsdottir_(Earth-616)/Appearances).

For example, *[Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2: Angela](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79673/in-the-prequel-trilogy-are-we-the-audience-intended-to-know-darth-sidious-tr)*:

[image]

However, there is no indication that she is in anyway the same character as the one appearing in *Spawn*. In addition to having completely different backstories, the original Angela

> dies in *Spawn* #100.